# Pre-Sale receives error: Canceled - Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]

Tags: tokens, erc-20, presale

I have 2 contracts

1. The first one cretes a token contract
2. The second creates pre-sale contract

Pre-sale contract created with 0.5 eth for paying for gas

When trying to send 0.5 ethereum to pre-sale contract - received error:
*Canceled -  Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]*

Anybody can help me with this error?

Thx,
attached both contracts below:

**Token contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
// https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Contract function to receive approval and execute function in one call
//
// Borrowed from MiniMeToken
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
    function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Owned contract
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract Owned {
    address public owner;
    address public newOwner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        newOwner = _newOwner;
    }

    function acceptOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = address(0);
    }
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC20 Token, with the addition of symbol, name and decimals and a
// fixed supply
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract VOBLA10 is ERC20Interface, Owned {
    using SafeMath for uint;

    string public symbol;
    string public  name;
    uint _totalSupply;
    uint8 public decimals;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor() public {
        symbol = "VLAB";
        name = "VOBLA10";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 300000000 * (10**uint(decimals));
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply.sub(balances[address(0)]);
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account `tokenOwner`
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to `to` account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`
    // from the token owner's account
    //
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer `tokens` from the `from` account to the `to` account
    //
    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
    // for spending from the `from` account and
    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
    // transferred to the spender's account
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for `spender` to transferFrom(...) `tokens`
    // from the token owner's account. The `spender` contract function
    // `receiveApproval(...)` is then executed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
        return true;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
        return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);
    }
}
```

**Pre-sale contract**

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24 <0.6.0;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract VoblaCrowdsaleTemp11 is ReentrancyGuard {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address private _wallet; // wallet of token owner
    uint256 private fundingGoal; // in ether -> 10K
    uint256 private amountRaised;
    uint256 private price;
    token private tokenReward;  // address of Vobla # should be token?

    uint256 private deadline;
    uint256 private minimum;

    bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    constructor(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo, // wallet of token owner
        uint fundingGoalInEthers, // 10K ether -> 10K * 170 tokens
        uint etherCostOfEachToken, // 170
        uint256 durationInMinutes,  // should check if solidity understands hours or days constant
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward // address of Vobla
    ) public payable {
        require(etherCostOfEachToken > 0);
        require(durationInMinutes > 0);
        require(ifSuccessfulSendTo != address(0));
        require(address(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward) != address(0));

        amountRaised = 0; // initial amount - in wei
        _wallet = ifSuccessfulSendTo; // wallet of token owner
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers*10**18; // 10K ether -> 10K * 170 tokens -> in wei
        price = etherCostOfEachToken*10**18; // price in wei per 1 ether
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward); // address of Vobla
        deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () public payable {
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        crowdsaleClosed = _isDeadlineReached(deadline);
        require(!crowdsaleClosed);
        require(msg.sender != address(0));

        uint256 amount = msg.value; // in wei
        require(amount > 0);

        crowdsaleClosed = _isGoalReached(amount);

        uint256 tokens = amount.mul(price);

        amountRaised = amountRaised.add(amount);

        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, tokens);

        _wallet.transfer(amount);
    }

    function _isGoalReached(uint256 weiAmount) internal view returns(bool) {
        return (amountRaised.add(weiAmount) >= fundingGoal);
    }

    function _isDeadlineReached(uint256 time) internal view returns(bool) {
        return (now >= time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really difficult to say without a lot more details. What I'd recommend is to etiher try to debug the contract or comment out the `require` statements one by one until you find out which reverts the contract.